# What's the easiest way to include french accents in an Entity Framework project?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-4

I am building a simple Entity framework 6 MVC web application that must hold French characters.  Currently, all french accented characters are being converted into "?" when entered into the database.

My project is a database base first project that is using localdb\v.11.0

Here is where I create my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items]
(
    [ItemId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(40) COLLATE French_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(80) COLLATE French_CI_AS NOT NULL, 
    [Start_Hour] DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    [End_Hour] DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL, 
)
```

Comment: Code first? Database first? Model first?

Comment: database first project.

Comment: Then TGH has your answer

Comment: tried that before and it is not helping :(

Comment: Then there is something else you are doing that requires us to see code to help.

Comment: I've appended my create statement...maybe that helps?

Comment: Not really, that looks fine though I don't think you need the collation settings. What are you doing to display and save data?

Comment: In visual studio, I use the new-query editor and simply write: select * dbo.Items;

Comment: And how did you get the data into the database?

Comment: Data is converted from a CSV file into a list of objects that are mapped to the database.  I use the addRange method

Comment: Are you opening the files as Unicode?

Comment: I'm not sure.  How can I check this? I'm a bit rookie

Answer (score 1):

Use datatype nvarchar to support unicode.